# How do i make nested for loop loops at one item at a time

Tags: loops, for-loop, polygon

I'm trying to test a function that checks if a polygon is valid or not and a valid polygon must not have any intersections within it's lines, and I'm checking that it's valid using a function i made named intersects.

lines: an array that contains a line (two points)

```
        for i in self.polygon.lines:
          for b in self.polygon.lines:
            if [b].intersects(i):
                self.assertFalse(self.polygon.is_valid())
```

However,  i can't seem to know how to check if the first line intersects with all lines and the second line intersects with all lines and so on. It seems to check each index with its item
how can i make it check for all possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

**Idea:** Take every edge of the polygon, and check whether it intersects with other nodes except itself or not.

```
for i in self.polygon.lines: # looping over each edge i
        for b in range(len(self.polygon.lines)): # nested looping over each edge b
                if b != i and self.polygon.lines[b].intersects(i): # checking whether i and b intersects or not
                        self.assertFalse(self.polygon.is_valid())
```

You just missed to include the check whether you are comparing the edge with itself or not (b != i).

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to do! the problem is in the two for loops it checks intersection of index 0 with the line 0 and so on it doesn't check index 0 with all lines then index 1 with all lines etc.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and mark it as excepted answer if it solves your problem. Cheers!